# Why does multi-catch RuntimeException compile but multi-catch Exception does not?

Tags: java, exception

In this example, the 2nd catch block is unreachable and therefore my code does not compile. However, if I make `LimpException` extend `RuntimeException` instead of `Exception`, it compiles without any trouble. Why?

```
public class Finals {

  public void run() {
    try {
      spit();
    } catch (HurtException e) {
      System.out.println("");
    } catch (LimpException ex) { // does not compile, unreachable code
      System.out.println("");
    }
  }

  public void spit() throws HurtException { // method that throws the Exception
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
  }
}

class LimpException extends Exception { // extends Exception vs extends
                                        // RuntimeException
}

class HurtException extends LimpException {
}
```

Comment: a runtime LimeException could always be thrown by someone down the stack... therefore the clause can be reached at runtime.

Comment: This comment explained the *why* much better than the posted answer. Thank you bayou.io!

Comment: To expand a little on @bayou.io's comment: As long as a `LimpException` is a checked exception, it is guaranteed that `spit` will not throw a `LimpException` (since it only declares `throws HurtException`!) If the `LimpException` is turned into a `RuntimeException` on the other hand, there is no such guarantee. A subclass of `Finals` could for instance override `spit` and throw a `LimpException`.

Comment: @aioobe - yes. also, even an all-mighty static analyzer should allow some room for future code change; one should be able to insert a `throw runtime exception` anywhere without breaking the code.

Comment: the compiler assumes that uncheck exception can arise from anywhere, even from empty statements! e.g. `try{}catch(RuntimeException e){}`. this is a ridiculous case. a more plausible case - ``try{}catch(JVMError e){}``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [JLS §11.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2):

> The unchecked exception classes (§11.1.1) are **exempted from compile-time checking.**

That's pretty simple. Even though that code block is still unreachable, the compiler simply doesn't check.

In your example, `LimpException` cannot be thrown from the try statement body that isn't already caught by the `catch LimpException` catch block. This is banned by [JLS §11.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3):

> It is a compile-time error if a catch clause can catch checked exception class E1 and it is not the case that the try block corresponding to the catch clause can throw a checked exception class that is a subclass or superclass of E1, unless E1 is Exception or a superclass of Exception.
>
> **It is a compile-time error if a catch clause can catch (§11.2) checked exception class E1 and a preceding catch clause of the immediately enclosing try statement can catch E1 or a superclass of E1.**